# Trying to use Edgewebbrowsers SubscribeToCDPEvent

Tags: delphi

Delphi has a demo with EdgeBrowser
I am trying to Subscribe to DevToolsProtocol using the follow.

```
   EdgeBrowser.SubscribeToCDPEvent('Log.enable');
   EdgeBrowser.SubscribeToCDPEvent('Log.entryAdded');
```

but  **EdgeBrowserDevToolsProtocolEventReceived** never fires.
Any help?

Comment: The first one at least is a method not an event.

Comment: yes thank you. but demo of embarcadero still not woriking. Thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

```
EdgeBrowser1.DefaultInterface.OpenDevToolsWindow;
```

starts DevTools

Remember, the WebBrowser component does not have this command, it only exists in the EdgeBrowser component.